# .gitcredentials vs .git-credentials

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

I've chosen to use file-based git-credential-store. That is, my credentials are saved in `~/.git-credentials` [as per documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store). (I am using Windows 10)

However, I can see that the folder now has two identical files, `.git-credentials` vs `.gitcredentials`. Deleting one makes the other reappear. So I ask:

1. is it a abnormal situation? Googling I only found 1 file as default
2. why did this happen? (maybe something specific to my machine?)
3. is there a way to keep only 1 file? (.git-credentials seems to be the "right" one)

Comment: A quick search of the git source finds no reference to a `.gitcredentials`. It must be something else.

Comment: with right password in git-credentials but not in gitcredentials, it worked and updated the wrong one. with wrong password in git-credentials but right in gitcredentials, it didn't worked and deleted the credential from both files